# Get name and email details when doing Facebook sign-up in ASP.Net MVC (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, entity-framework, facebook-graph-api

I have managed to get Facebook sign-up and sign-in working using the following tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

I have also read on the Facebook App Development site about request permissions for details such as name and email...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

In relation to this, I found the "Configure App Center Permissions" button on the "App Details" page in the Facebook developer centre.  I was able to add "email" as requested permission.  It is my understanding the first name and last name are available from the public profile.

I don't know how long these settings take to filter through, but when I went to sign-up with Facebook it said that it was only requesting my public profile and friends list, no email.

**Razor Code**

That Razor code from my external login partial view looks like this (standard view from the project template...HTML has been removed)...

```
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security
...
@{
    var loginProviders;
    var context = Context.GetOwinContext();
    loginProviders = context.Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();

    if (loginProviders.Count() > 0)
    {
        string action = Model.Action // ExternalLogin;
        string returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl;
        using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
            {
                @* create submit button using p.AuthenticationType
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Account Controller**

The account controller code that handles this request is ("provider" is Facebook which is the AuthenticationType from the form):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    return new ChallengeResult(
        provider, 
        Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

**Account Controller - ChallengeResult**

```
private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(
        string provider, 
        string redirectUri) 
        : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
    {
    }

    public ChallengeResult(
        string provider, 
        string redirectUri, 
        string userId)
    {
        this.LoginProvider = provider;
        this.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
        this.UserId = userId;
    }

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }

    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        if (UserId != null)
        {
            properties.Dictionary["XsrfId"] = UserId;
        }

        var authContext = context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        authContext.Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

I get the feeling that something needs to be done in the ChallengeResult class.  Perhaps add extra AuthenticationProperties.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add "email" criterion in FacebookAuthenticationOptions's scope in MVC 5, it requests email permission from users. You didn't post your Startup.Auth.cs but I think you used default Facebook Authentication.

Try using custom FacebookAuthentication options, like that:

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //   consumerKey: "",
        //   consumerSecret: "");

        //Customizing FacebookAuthenticationOptions...
        var facebookOptions=new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "***",
            AppSecret = "***"
        };
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email"); //We want to get user's email information by adding it in scope.
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```